# How to prevent more than once instance of chrome app being open at a time?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I just discovered I can launch more than one instance of my first chrome app at a time.  And they stack directly on top of one another, which does not make it immediately detectable.  Is there some kind of flag or lock file I can look for on startup?

Comment: How exactly did you launch the app? Was it installed from the Chrome Web Store, as a CRX file, or loaded as unpacked?

Comment: chrome canary, developer mode, loaded as unpacked extension.

Comment: Post your code. There is only one event page running, but your app code might be erroneously creating multiple windows.

Comment: It will take me some to slim down the project, ensure that it still produces the same error, and post it on github...

Comment: Can't speak for others, but I would never provide an answer if it involved looking at code on github, or anywhere else but right here. It's best (in my opinion) to post the code directly in your question. From what I understand of the problem, it should be possible to provide an example in <20 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give your app window an ID the system will only ever create one of it. The next time the window is 'created' the system will focus the existing window. Check out the [`CreateWindowOptions.id`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-CreateWindowOptions) field for more info.